# Random Variables independently distributed

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable, discrete-data

Q) Find an example of two discrete random variables $X$ and $Y$ such that $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution, but the event $X = Y$ *never* occurs.

Now I thought of these as distributions that are identical but not necessarily independent.

So we can't say whether they are i.i.d. or not.

After this I tried making a table of $X$ and $Pr(X)$ and $Y$ and $Pr(Y)$ but I just couldn't think how to construct one where $Pr(X=Y)$ is zero.

If it were continuous I could have said that since the probabilities at a point at zero for a continuous distribution I can say that $Pr(X=Y) = 0$

But this is a discrete case. Please assist me in this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Try $Y = 1-X$ where $X$ is a Bernoulli random variable with parameter $\frac 12$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Oh man. That was quick ! Bernoulli yes! Thanks Dilip

Comment: The parameter doesn't even need to be 1/2.  For any 0<p<1 when X=1, Y=0 and vice versa.

Comment: @MichaelChernick If the parameter is not $\frac 12$, then $X$ and $Y=1-X$ don't have the same distribution as the OP wants them to have.

Comment: Yes I didn't think of that.

Comment: There is a perfectly general procedure, of which the examples in these comments and the answers are special cases: Given any bivariate random variable $(X,Y)$ with identically distributed marginals, truncate it by removing the diagonal (where $X=Y$). I believe *all* solutions to your problem arise this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Find an example of two discrete random variables $X$ and $Y$ such that $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution, but the event $X = Y$ never occurs.

Suppose $X$ is the outcome of a fair dice, i.e., $X$ is uniformly distributed over $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$. $Y = X + 1$, except when $X = 6$, in which case $Y = 1$. Then $Y$, too, is uniformly distributed over $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$, but it is impossible for it to be equal to $X$.

Comment: Shouldn't Y just be equal to $(X+1)%6$ ? Because if we put X = 1 then (1+1)%6 will give 2 because 2 divided by 6 yields a remainder of 2. But if we add 1 to it like we did in your expression then we would get Y = 3 at X = 1 . Won't we ? But I am honestly amazed at the brevity and clear cut approach you have used. Ingenious

Comment: Alright yes. That's correct now. Thanks a lot. This was very insightful .

Comment: @user435390 You're probably right. modulo + 1-based counting drives me to mistakes. Wrote it in words. Thanks.